# Build Lambda select from array

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have an array which has column names and need to be added in the lambda select

```
selectArray = {"Name", "Email", "LastUpdated"}
```

and depending on the array the lambda select statement should change

```
var list = customer.Select(s => new {s.Name, s.Email, s.LastUpdated}).Distinct().ToList();
```

The values and length of the selectArray will change.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: I am generating that array based on user's UI change.

Comment: It is List<Customer> and the values in the array will be any of the properties under Customer class.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to ask a rhetorical question. What about something like: `customer.Select(Customer.From(selections))...`?

Comment: Customer object is from EF DataContext and doesn't have a From

Comment: The customer is likely an entity that you have some amount of control over including adding extension methods or creating other classes that work with them.